# MYSQL - table size seems not normal

Tags: mysql, indexing, size

I have a table with a schema like this :

```
id int(10) PK,
fk_id int(10) FK,
c3 int(10),
c4 timestamp,
c5 tinyint(3),
c6 varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci,
c7 tinyint(3),
c8 tinyint(3),
c9 tinyint(1)
```

Now this table has 10,000 records and its size is 1.8 MB which the size of indexes is 0.3 MB and size of data is 1.5 MB according to what MYSQL says.

But all records for the filed c6 are almost 10 or 15 character length strings, and if you calculate the maximum incoming size it would be like this:

(4+4+4+4+1+15+1+1+1)*10000 = 350 KB

But the data size is 1500 KB. Now I'm confused why the size of this table is growing with a high rate and don't know the reason of this difference. Is it possible that MYSQL is showing wrong data size? or maybe wrong combination of index size and data size? or any other reason?

I'm really confused , thanks for your help.

Comment: Out of curiousity, if you do a `SHOW TABLE STATUS` what does it show for the `Avg_row_length`?  My guess is that MySQL is allocating extra space for growth and your numbers are including that extra empty space.

Comment: it shows 143 for `Avg_row_length`

Comment: And what database engine are you using? MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: that's InnoDB and the table default collation is `utf8_general_ci` but the only varchar field collation is `latin`

Comment: InnoDB autoextends the shared tablespace file. The ibdata file is essentially empty in a fresh installation, yet its size is 10MB by default. Also, if you delete records, the file size will remain unchanged, it will just keep growing.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would suggest would be to optimize the table

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE mytable
```

I would expect there to be some overhead for InnoDB, see here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-physical-record.html

but not as much as you've indicated.  Could be that there is fragmentation and unused space, especially if you do frequent inserts and updates to that table.  Optimizing the table should reclaim that space.

Comment: well this table doesn't have any updates , but lots of inserts in each period. and this table is growing very fast and it should be optimized for millions of records. well I don't need foreign key constraints and as I said , I don't need updates, just inserts and select. because the performance of select is really important, and I also need indexes, what's your suggestion . does converting table engine to `MYISAM` help me?

Comment: @ali - Switching to MyISAM might help, but is probably not the best solution.  What do you get if you run the `OPTIMIZE` command for the table?

Comment: I ran that command and said `ok`, but no change in the table size when I run `show table status`

Comment: @ali - interesting, if that's the case and you are really concerned about disk space you may want to try to convert it to MyISAM as that engine does have less overhead.  Keep in mind that you will lose transaction support for that table though (if that's important).